# wiring Tamura 4 pin hall effect current transducer to differential daq

Tags: ac, differential, transducer, daq

How do i wire a 4 pin hall sensor:
200A model below

https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/397/L03SXXXD15-469349.pdf

I don't understand the wiring schematic below [image]

I currently have +15 to pin 1, -15 to pin 2, V high from das to pin 3, Vlo from das to pin4.  Power is from a regulated power supply. The only way for me to get reasonable data to the das is to jump the 10k ohm between pin 4 and -15.  Is this correct?

Comment: The bigger question is ; what is the signal bandwidth of 200A and what is considered noise?  such as crosstalk from 100A transient in say 20~2000 microseconds should be 2V signal +/-1% and not affected by CdV/dt or LdI/dt of crosstalk. What is the cable and ground design?

Comment: I'm measuring the output of an RC ESC,  switching frequency is 8khz.  it approximates a sine wave between 100-800hz.  3 phase being measured is floating (DC battery pack providing power). Daq and power supply are grounded to earth (AC wall power)

Comment: OK if you are using this for servo current feedback then 800Hz is frequency BW but Phase needs to be greater BW  while rejecting 8kHz is noise but also phase shift can be noise and more likely transients  due to current commutation risetime and sampling time of ADC.  Some care in shielding of signals from motor current commutation and cable orientation with coupling of motor commutation noise.  I wonder what sampling rate and anti-aliasing filter phase shift exists on signal.  Did you analyze aliasing and cross-talk effects yet?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the diagram one row of figures up, on the right.  Pin 3 is your output voltage, and is connected to ground  (not -15) through a 10K resistor.  I don't know what you mean by "das"

Comment: data acq system I suspect.

Comment: DAS/DAQ data acquisition.  I am doing differential sensing on the daq so i have vhi/vlo instead of V and ground to the daq.  Maybe thats my issue?  Ill go single ended and try what you mentioned.  I dont trust/understand the schematic because it has +15 and -15 both going to ground,  when i do this it shorts the power supply.

Comment: Then you have something wrong with your power scheme.  Both power supplies must be reference to Ground, as usual.  There is some nastiness going on with the battery symbol looking like it connects to other pins, but it does not.

Comment: For power i have  a meanwell 24V din rail supply + a buck converter to drop to 15V.  Link below.  Power supply and DAQ each have their own ground.  Since pin 4 is labeled 0V above do you think it is intended to be ground reference for signal?  ALso thanks for the help

https://www.alliedelec.com/product/mean-well-usa/mdr-20-24/70069737/?gclid=CjwKCAiA8K7uBRBBEiwACOm4d4PY3_twm5nuz8QlMuFc-0j9V7dxy92172ULeCtpKqJa6OivwuXXAhoCjSYQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: 0V is ground.  I don't know how DIN power modules work.  They may ALREADY be grounded to your Chassis, for all I know.

Comment: @donrafa7: that sensor requires a bipolar power supply: +15 V, -15 V and 0 V/Ground.  From your description you have a single 15 V supply.

Comment: the power supply has +V and -V output,  i looked into Bipolar/ 4 quadrant supplies is that what you mean?